# how to get the items base in json objects

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have this return after the ajax POST in javascript

```
Object {d: "{"Success":true,"Message":"success test"}"}
```

I want to get the Success value and Message value.
Any idea how to do this in javascript and knockoutjs?

This is the code for ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "ManualOfferEx.aspx/OnSubmit",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            var data = result.d;
            console.log(ko.toJS(data));
            //console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status + "\nresponseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you fiddle what you have so far?

Comment: First: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: that object above is the return result for Ajax POST.

Comment: Can you also post the viewmodels code including the ajax call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this should work for you:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "ManualOfferEx.aspx/OnSubmit",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            var data = result.d;
            var success = data.Success;
            var message = data.Message;
            console.log(message);
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status + "\nresponseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Also, you had a call to ko.toJS().  You only need to do that if you're trying to convert a Knockout model/object to a JS object.  Since you're doing an Ajax call, the result of the call is already a JS object.